# ReRender child component of FlatList - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist that is rendered with dynamic data, Here is the heirarchy of components used.

- FlatList

  - List Item
  - Image
  - Button

Now these child components are rendered via "RenderItem" method of Flatlist, and everything works fine as expected, Now When I want to change any "prop" of the button by using "state" it changes the state (i can see in log) but just cant see changes to the button, which means the button is not rendered after change of state, it works fine if i use it out of the Flatlist Component, but inside, it doesnot work at all.

Any Idea Why?

Comment: any code or repo so we can test this?

Comment: flatlist is a pure component. Is your button's state not directly in the root of your state? So you are not changing the whole state to force rerender but just a tiny bit somewhere deep?

Comment: Same issue. How can we reset childcomponent's (renderItem) state?